# Including type_traits in visual studio 2010 compile errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, type-traits

I am trying to #include  in my program but I am getting errors in type_traits.

I broke it down and found out it is the #include  statement when it all goes wrong.

I'm able to get it working in visual studio 2015 but unfortunately I need to compile in VS2010 for my application.

Here are the compile errors that I am getting.

```
1>  ExamplePlugin.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(762): error C2275: '_Ty' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(764) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_standard_layout<_Ty>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(762): error C3861: '__is_standard_layout': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(763): error C2955: 'std::_Cat_base' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtr1common(53) : see declaration of 'std::_Cat_base'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(768): error C2275: '_Ty' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(770) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_literal_type<_Ty>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(768): error C3861: '__is_literal_type': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(769): error C2955: 'std::_Cat_base' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtr1common(53) : see declaration of 'std::_Cat_base'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(774): error C2275: '_Ty' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(776) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_trivial<_Ty>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(774): error C3861: '__is_trivial': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(775): error C2955: 'std::_Cat_base' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtr1common(53) : see declaration of 'std::_Cat_base'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(1015): warning C4346: 'std::is_array<_Ty>::value' : dependent name is not a type
1>          prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(1018) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_trivially_constructible<_Ty,_Ty,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(1015): error C2144: syntax error : 'std::remove_reference<_Ty>::type' should be preceded by ')'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(1015): error C3861: '__is_trivially_copyable': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(1017): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(1018): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\type_traits(1018): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Does anyone know why I can't include type_traits?
I have tried reinstalling VS2010 but it didn't appear to make any difference.
For what it's worth, I am on Windows 10 64 bit and my visual studio version is:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Professional

Microsoft Office Developer Tools   01018-532-2002102-70847
Microsoft Office Developer Tools

Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01018-532-2002102-70847
Microsoft Visual Basic 2010

Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01018-532-2002102-70847
Microsoft Visual C# 2010

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010   01018-532-2002102-70847
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Microsoft Visual F# 2010   01018-532-2002102-70847
Microsoft Visual F# 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer   01018-532-2002102-70847
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01018-532-2002102-70847
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

Critical Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2938807)   KB2938807
This critical update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this critical update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2938807.

Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010   
Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2529927)   KB2529927
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2529927.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2542054)   KB2542054
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2542054.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2548139)   KB2548139
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2548139.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2549864)   KB2549864
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549864.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2565057)   KB2565057
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565057.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2635973)   KB2635973
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2635973.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2890573)   KB2890573
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2890573.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB3002340)   KB3002340
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3002340.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools   10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Developer Tools

NVIDIA® Nsight™ Tegra Development Platform, Visual Studio Edition   3.1.15202.6244
NVIDIA® Nsight™ Tegra Visual Studio Edition provides tools for Android development. 
Copyright © NVIDIA Corporation 2015.
User Guide available at: http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/mobile/nsight_tegra/nsight_tegra_main.htm

Includes technology developed by Mentor Embedded (http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software).

vs-android is Copyright © 2011 Gavin Pugh (http://www.gavpugh.com). Vs-android contains minor modifications from the original source produced by Gavin Pugh.

Android XML parser for .NET is Copyright © 2012 Markus Jarderot. Android XML parser for .NET contains modifications from the original source produced by Markus Jarderot.

Warning: This computer program is protected by copyright law and international treaties. Unauthorized reproduction or distribution of this program, or any portion of it, may result in severe civil and criminal penalties, and will be prosecuted to the maximum extent possible under the law.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2644980)   KB2644980
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2644980.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU (KB2645410)   KB2645410
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2645410.
```

Thanks in advance for any insights people may have.

-Alex

Comment: Is this really reproducible on a .cpp file which contains only the one line `#include <type_traits>` and nothing else?

Comment: @Angew Yup it is reproducible in the following code:
    #include <type_traits>
    int main():
    {
        int number = 5;
    }

Comment: Are there any forced include files in your project? Are you using a Platform Toolset other than the default?

Comment: My platform toolset is v100 and I didn't change that so I assume it's default.
And I've got no include directories set

Comment: Yes, v100 is the default in VS 2010. Is that a pure C++ project or are there some MS-specifics (CLR, C++-CLI, C#) mixed in?

Comment: It's an Empty Visual C++ project

Comment: I do have visual studio 2015 and 2013 installed as well. I'm going to try uninstalling those right now, I don't think they would be affecting this, but you never know.

Comment: That didn't help any, I'm just going to install it in a vm for now.